# For Facebook events is choosing "ignore" the same as choosing "remove event"?

Tags: facebook-events

When I am not interested in invited events, I click the upper-right [x] button to remove the events.

I'm not sure whether there is a difference between the "ignore" button and the [x] button.

Is there a official explanation for it?

Answer (score 2):

If you click the 'x', or remove event, it takes you off the guest list. 
That way you don't have to answer whether or not you "Can Go" or "Can't Go".

In events where the options are "Interested" rather than can/can't go, I'm pretty sure it should be the same (i.e., the distinction between removing an event and answering whether or not you're interested is analogous to the case above).

"Ignore" doesn't seem to take you off the guest list, whereas removing event (or clicking 'x') does.